# Is there a way to phone somebody and play an audio file in android?

Tags: android, audio, telephony

I would like to create an ermergency call application : if triggered, it calls a given number and play an audio file, giving the information the caller couldn't give himself.

For that I need to engage a call but ensure that I can replace any sound from the speaker with an played audio file. Can I do that in android ? What's the way ?

Comment: I don't know how to help you, but this sounds like a great idea for an app.  Do you have any idea how time-consuming it is to call all the people I'm stalking breathe into the phone?  Can you add a feature so that it calls every hour or so?

Comment: My gran father is 86 and he has an emergency call button in his bedroom. Nothing for outside, and I'd like to create this app for this kind of use. Heart attack, child emergency, etc. It's not because you can make a bad use of a tech that it should prevent you from creating it or you would not have P2P, freenet, mass mailling, keyloggers, and else.

Comment: @e-satis Have you found the solution to this problem ?

Comment: No, I didn't. I'm having more hope to be able to do that with boot2gecko.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this with the G1 at this time, because two different processors handle the call and the apps, and there is no path between them.  AFAIK this isn't in the SDK yet, but assuming hardware comes out that can do it, it will be added to the SDK.

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/d04c307973345fef/a628e578900b3dce?lnk=gst&q=dave+sparks+play+audio#a628e578900b3dce